# Сделать код лаконичнее

Tags: ооп, инспекция-кода, наследование, c++-cli

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();    // why? [1]
    virtual void save(QJsonObject &json) const { json["id"] = _id; }
    virtual void open(const QJsonObject &json) {
        _id = json["id"].toInt();
        if (idStatic <= _id) {
            idStatic = _id + 1;
        }
    }
    enum { Type = 0 };
    virtual int type() const { return Type; }
    int id() {  return _id;}
protected:
    int _id;
    static int idStatic;
    Base() : _id(idStatic++) {}
    Base(const QJsonObject &json) { open(json); }
};
int Base::idStatic = 0;
Base::~Base() {}    // why? [1]

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived1() : Base(), param1(_id * 10) {}
    Derived1(const QJsonObject &json) : Base(json) { open(json); }
    ~Derived1() override;    // why? [2]
    enum { Type = Base::Type + 1 };
    int type() const override { return Type; }

    int param1;

    void save(QJsonObject &json) const override {
        json["Type"] = Type;
        json["param1"] = param1;
        Base::save(json);
    }
    void open(const QJsonObject &json) override {
        int type = json["Type"].toInt();
        if (type != Type) {
            throw 1;
        }
        param1 = json["param1"].toInt();
        Base::open(json);
    }
};
Derived1::~Derived1() {}    // why? [2]

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2() : Base(), param2(_id * 2) {}
    Derived2(const QJsonObject &json) : Base(json) { open(json); }
    ~Derived2() override;   // why? [2]
    enum { Type = Base::Type + 2 };
    int type() const override { return Type; }

    int param2;

    void save(QJsonObject &json) const override {
        json["Type"] = Type;
        json["param2"] = param2;
        Base::save(json);
    }
    void open(const QJsonObject &json) override {
        int type = json["Type"].toInt();
        if (type != Type) {
            throw 2;
        }
        param2 = json["param2"].toInt();
        Base::open(json);
    }
};
Derived2::~Derived2() {}    // why? [2]


Base *openBase(const QJsonObject &json) {   // [3]
    int type = json["Type"].toInt();
    if (type == Derived1::Type) {
        return new Derived1(json);
    } else if (type == Derived2::Type) {
        return new Derived2(json);
    } else {
        throw 3;
    }
}

int main(int , char *[])
{
    // запись файла
    {
        QList<Base*> l;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i & 1) {
                l.append(new Derived1());
            } else {
                l.append(new Derived2());
            }
        }
        QJsonObject json;
        QJsonArray jsonArray;
        foreach (Base *b, l) {
            QJsonObject j;
            b->save(j);
            jsonArray.append(j);
        }
        json["objects"] = jsonArray;

        QFile saveFile("test.json");
        if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            qWarning("Couldn't open saveFile.");
            return false;
        }
        QJsonDocument saveJson(json);
        saveFile.write(saveJson.toJson());
        saveFile.close();
    }
    // чтение файла
    {
        QFile openFile("test.json");
        if (!openFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            qWarning("Couldn't open openFile.");
        }
        QJsonDocument openJson(QJsonDocument::fromJson(openFile.readAll()));
        const QJsonObject json = openJson.object();
        QJsonArray jsonArray = json["objects"].toArray();
        QList<Base *> l;
        foreach (QJsonValue j, jsonArray) {
            Base *b = openBase(j.toObject());
            l.append(b);
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "Done";

    return 0;
}
```

**[1]** Зачем делать виртуальный деструктор у базового класса? Как можно сделать код красивее, что бы не писать `{}`?
**[2]** Зачем делать деструктор у производного класса? Как можно сделать код красивее?
**[3]** Можно ли как нибудь переделать программу, что бы не делать отдельную ф-цию для парсинга файла(`openBase`)? Если у меня будет 200 производных классов, мне так же через else if (switch) перебирать все классы? можно это как то красивее сделать?

---

После доработки по примеру @Harry, лаконичность немного падает, но функциональность растет.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base(); // = default;  не дефайлт, тк возникает предупреждение
    virtual void save(QJsonObject &json) const { json["id"] = _id; }
    virtual void open(const QJsonObject &json) {
        _id = json["id"].toInt();
        if (idStatic <= _id) {
            idStatic = _id + 1;
        }
    }
    enum { Type = 0 };
    virtual int type() const { return Type; }
    int id() {  return _id;}
    static Base *getObj(const QJsonObject &json);
protected:
    int _id;
    static int idStatic;
    Base() : _id(idStatic++) {}
    Base(const QJsonObject &json) { open(json); }
    static void registrationDerived(int type, Base *(*make)(const QJsonObject &));
private:
    static Base *_make(const QJsonObject &json) { return new Base(json);}
    static QMap<int, Base*(*)(const QJsonObject &)> _deriveds;  // все так же работает, если вместо QMap использовать std::map
};
int Base::idStatic = 0;
Base::~Base() {}
QMap<int, Base*(*)(const QJsonObject &)> Base::_deriveds {{Base::Type, Base::_make}};

void Base::registrationDerived(int type, Base *(*make)(const QJsonObject &) ) {
    _deriveds[type] = make;
}

Base *Base::getObj(const QJsonObject &json) {
    return _deriveds[json["Type"].toInt()](json);
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived1() : Base(), param1(_id * 10) {}
    Derived1(const QJsonObject &json) : Base(json) { open(json); }
    ~Derived1() override;
    enum { Type = Base::Type + 1 };
    int type() const override { return Type; }

    int param1;

    void save(QJsonObject &json) const override {
        json["Type"] = Type;
        json["param1"] = param1;
        Base::save(json);
    }
    void open(const QJsonObject &json) override {
        int type = json["Type"].toInt();
        if (type != Type) {
            throw 1;
        }
        param1 = json["param1"].toInt();
        Base::open(json);
    }
private:
    static Base *_make(const QJsonObject &json) { return new Derived1(json);}
    static struct reg {
        reg() { Base::registrationDerived(Derived1::Type, _make); }
    } _r;
};
Derived1::reg Derived1::_r;
Derived1::~Derived1() {}

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2() : Base(), param2(_id * 2) {}
    Derived2(const QJsonObject &json) : Base(json) { open(json); }
    ~Derived2() override;
    enum { Type = Base::Type + 2 };
    int type() const override { return Type; }

    int param2;

    void save(QJsonObject &json) const override {
        json["Type"] = Type;
        json["param2"] = param2;
        Base::save(json);
    }
    void open(const QJsonObject &json) override {
        int type = json["Type"].toInt();
        if (type != Type) {
            throw 2;
        }
        param2 = json["param2"].toInt();
        Base::open(json);
    }
private:
    static Base *_make(const QJsonObject &json) { return new Derived2(json);}
    static struct reg {
        reg() { Base::registrationDerived(Derived2::Type, _make); }
    } _r;
};
Derived2::reg Derived2::_r;
Derived2::~Derived2() {}

int main(int , char *[])
{
    // запись файла
    {
        QList<Base*> l;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i & 1) {
                l.append(new Derived1());
            } else {
                l.append(new Derived2());
            }
        }
        QJsonObject json;
        QJsonArray jsonArray;
        foreach (Base *b, l) {
            QJsonObject j;
            b->save(j);
            jsonArray.append(j);
        }
        json["objects"] = jsonArray;

        QFile saveFile("test.json");
        if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            qWarning("Couldn't open saveFile.");
            return false;
        }
        QJsonDocument saveJson(json);
        saveFile.write(saveJson.toJson());
        saveFile.close();
    }
    // чтение файла
    {
        QFile openFile("test.json");
        if (!openFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            qWarning("Couldn't open openFile.");
        }
        QJsonDocument openJson(QJsonDocument::fromJson(openFile.readAll()));
        const QJsonObject json = openJson.object();
        QJsonArray jsonArray = json["objects"].toArray();
        QList<Base *> l;
        foreach (QJsonValue j, jsonArray) {
            Base *b = Base::getObj(j.toObject());
            l.append(b);
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "Done";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `virtual ~Base() = default;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По третьему пункту - как-то пришлось командой делать программу, где каждый писал свой класс-наследник, примерно так же вот. Чтоб подключать новые классы без возни - в базовом была статическая коллекция, грубо - `map` (это было очень давно, еще до STL), в которой каждому идентификатору класса соответствовал свой фабричный метод, возвращающий нужного потомка. Была статическая функция в базовом классе, которая добавляла новую запись в эту коллекцию. Ну, а потом аналог вашего `openBase` просто искал нужную фабрику...

Каждый класс-потомок в начале работы регистрировался в базовом классе (более того, это потом переписали так, что регистрация происходила автоматически, при инициализации статического члена потомка), ну, а дальше все понятно...

Так что вся работа по добавлению потомка сводилась к созданию своего класса в отдельном .cpp - с определенными, по сути описанными выше правилами - и подключением этого .cpp в проект. Ни в одном другом файле ничего менять не приходилось.

Вот примерный набросок с учетом нынешних реалий :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void doit() { cout << "Base\n"; }

    static void regist(int type, Base*(*f)()) { (*getBase())[type] = f; }
    static Base * getObj(int type) { return getBase()->at(type)(); }

private:
    static Base * make() { return new Base; }
    static map<int,Base*(*)()> * getBase()
    {
        static map<int,Base*(*)()> m{{0,Base::make}};
        return &m;
    }
};



class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void doit() { cout << "Derived1\n"; }
private:
    static Base * make() { return new Derived1; }
    struct reg {
        reg() { Base::regist(1,make); }
    };
    inline static reg r;
};


class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void doit() { cout << "Derived2\n"; }
private:
    static Base * make() { return new Derived2; }
    struct reg {
        reg() { Base::regist(2,make); }
    };
    inline static reg r;
};

int main()
{
    for(int i: {0, 1, 2, 3})
    {
        try {
            Base::getObj(i)->doit();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout << "Wrong type\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Все, после этого любой класс может располагаться в отдельном файле - он будет подхвачен и корректно отработан в основном файле. *Никуда вносить информацию о нем не требуется*.

Можно в принципе прикрутить шаблоны, чтоб писать еще меньше кода - структура-то регистрации одинакова... - но это уже как ДЗ :) Мне было главное показать принцип.

Comment: Огонь =) Интересно =)

Comment: Там у ТС Qt используется, сюда ещё можно QUuid прикрутить, тоже статическое поле в каждом наследнике, чтобы об идентификаторах не договариваться, у какого наследника какой номер

Comment: @vegorov если покажешь маленький пример как пользоваться QUuid, буду благодарен

Comment: @Harry зачем inline при инициализации структуры?

Comment: Да чтоб не выносить и не инициализировать ее вне класса. Можно и без inline, но тогда нудно определение ее вне класса...

Comment: Qt ругается на inline: `inline variables are a C++17 extension`

Comment: Тогда, если компилятор все еще не понимает C++17 (посмотрите на ключики, может, его можно включить - он же сообразил, что это C++17) - тогда делайте, как [тут](https://ideone.com/q56nI2).

Answer (score 3):

Виртуальный деструктор у базового класса нужен, что бы в случае, если объект удаляется по указателю на базовый класс (если точнее - то статический и динамический тип отличаются), то будет UB (неопределенное поведение). До 11 стандарта это не было специфицированно и были всякие фантазии, что именно там происходит (например, "неполное удаление").

Поэтому, если Вы начинающий программист и делаете класс, от которого будете наследоваться - делайте виртуальный деструктор.

А вот уже в классах наследниках деструкторы будут автоматически виртуальны и их можно даже не писать (если сам класс сделан с поддержкой [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Но иногда бывает нужно все таки освобождать какие специфические ресурсы (особенно, если это спецобертки для системых функций), то тогда конечно лучше написать корректный деструктор. Но если RAII сделан правильно (умные указатели и подобное), то деструктор можно и не писать.

С третим пунктом немного сложнее. Да, можно сделать if, но это много. Можно сделать через switch-case. Я в свое время делал макрос, и тогда писать длинный if или switch не нужно.

```
#define CHECK(cl) if (type == cl::Type) {\
        return new cl(json);\
    } else

Base *openBase(const QJsonObject &json) {   // [3]
    int type = json["Type"].toInt();
    CHECK(Derived1)
    CHECK(Derived2)
    {
        throw 3;
    }
}
```

А если к этому прикрутить [X Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), то можно сократить код и в других местах.

Также, можно сделать map, в которой хранить соответствие имя-функция. В некоторых случаях это может быть оптимально.

P.S. Могут набежать любители "чистого с++ кода" и сказать, что в с++ макросы не хорошо использовать. Но может они предложат, как нагородить все это на шаблонной магии (но без макросов).

Comment: Без макросов и шаблонной магии - см. у меня в ответе :)

Comment: Макросы зло. Никогда не видели макросы min/max в других либах? Которые ломают std::min/std::max. Если не видели - значит повезло.

Comment: все может быть плохо и хорошо. Иногда один макрос может сделать больше, чем километры шаблонов. Один goto больше чем разувесистая система классов.

Answer (score 1):

Третий вопрос решается с помощью функционального программирования. Создаёте массив функций для ассоциирования типа как число к указателю на функцию. Далее просто вызываете функцию которая хранится в массиве по индексу типа. Пример рабочий такой:

```
# include <iostream>
class QJsonnObject { } ;
class Base {
public:
enum { Type = 0 };
Base(){}
Base(QJsonnObject const &);
 } ;

typedef Base * (*openBaseF)(QJsonnObject const & )  ;
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
enum { Type = Base::Type + 1 };
Derived1(QJsonnObject const &);
 } ;
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
enum { Type = Base::Type + 2 };
Derived2(QJsonnObject const &);
 } ;

Base::Base(QJsonnObject const &){
  std::cout<<"newBase"<<std::endl;}

Base * newBase(QJsonnObject const & j){
  return new Base (j);}

Derived1::Derived1(QJsonnObject const &){
  std::cout<<"newDerived1"<<std::endl;}  

Base * newDerived1(QJsonnObject const & j){
  return new Derived1 (j);}

Derived2::Derived2(QJsonnObject const &){
  std::cout<<"newDerived2"<<std::endl;}  

Base * newDerived2(QJsonnObject const & j){
  return new Derived2 (j);}

# define arrayOfopenBaseFSize 3

openBaseF arrayOfopenBaseF[arrayOfopenBaseFSize];

Base * openBase(QJsonnObject const & j){
  //int type = json["Type"].toInt();
  int type = 1 ;
  return arrayOfopenBaseF[type](j); }

int main(){
  arrayOfopenBaseF[Base::Type] = newBase ;
  arrayOfopenBaseF[Derived1::Type] = newDerived1 ;
  arrayOfopenBaseF[Derived2::Type] = newDerived2 ;

  QJsonnObject j ;
  Base * result = openBase(j);

  }
```

Comment: Минус решения - все равно нужно каждый класс руками дописывать в массив - как у ТС в его if-else/switch...